# how to run npm build from bash script triggered by cronjob?

Tags: cron, nodejs, npm

I have a very simple bash script (run-build.sh):

```
cd /var/www/project
npm run build
```

This script works fine when I run it from the command line but I want to run it every 30 minutes via a cron job:

```
*/30 * * * * /var/www/project/run-build.sh >> /var/www/test.log 2>&1
```

Which for some reason doesn't work.  I have tried various other approaches such as running the cron job as root user or adding the path to node as part of the cron job.  However I haven't managed to find a solution yet which is why I am now posting here.

Anyone have any ideas how to get this cron job to work?

Answer (score 2):

I updated my cronjob to:

```
* */12 * * * sudo -u user /var/www/project/run-build.sh >> /var/www/test.log 2>&1
```

and it now works. I'm sure I tried that before but I must have tried something different.

Comment: I don't think granting sudo access in crontab is the *best* solution but it worked for me having failed to set PATH variables and what not. +1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, the issue was due to my .sh script not having execution permissions.

Check if the script file has execution permission (`x` flag) with `ll`. If not, something like:

```
chmod 744 file
```

should allow your user to execute it without root.